# Surround.vim deletes selection

Tags: plugin-vim-surround

I'm trying to use [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) plugin and make a basic surround with a `"` sign. Documents states that i need to for example select a word with `v` and press `s"`. However, i'm not able to use that nor any other surround command because `s` char removes my selection and enters interactive mode. So basically using `Vs"` on `example_string` string gives me `"` instead of `"example_string"`.

Thanks in advance for any clues!

Comment: Read the docs! I believe you have to use `S"` in visual mode.

Comment: Well...there is a small `s` letter in the docs everywhere. However, i've tried with big `S` and it worked :) thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have this in my `.vimrc`:

```
map S ysiw
```

Mnemonic: "you surround in word".
Since this is by far my most used scenario for surround capitol S seemed like a good shortcut.

```
:help surround
```

does definitly help you with more examples.